# Infinite Sequences and Series Book arrangement over table

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose one has a large supply of books, all the same size, and you stack them at the edge
of a table, with each book extending farther beyond the edge of the table than the one
beneath it. Show that it is possible to do this so that the top book extends entirely beyond the
table. In fact, show that the top book can extend any distance at all beyond the edge of the
table if the stack is high enough. Use the following method of stacking: The top book extends
half its length beyond the second book. The second book extends a quarter of its length
beyond the third. The third extends one-sixth of its length beyond the fourth, and so on.

Comment: On the assumption you are not asking us to do this physically, consider half the harmonic series

Comment: Many use playing cards to do this experiment. It's the same technique used by the Romans to build the arches of their aqueducts.